# Jquery say that I try to make a cross domain call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

Becouse I have many dinamicly created data (in popover window) I need to create ann function like this:

```
function addOffer() {

    var token = document.getElementsByName('_token')[0].value;
    var s1 = $('.hstart').val();
    var p1 = $('.spin').val();
$.ajax({
  url: '/offers',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
     price: p1,
     start: s1,
     _token: token
  },

});
};
```

Now I call this function with:

```
 $('.addBid').click(function() {
addOffer();
});
```

and request is send to backend but then I get:  [image]

> k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @   jquery.js:8630

**UPDATE:**
In Laravel backend I have only:

```
public function store(Requests\OfferRequest $request)
    {

            $offer = new Offer($request->all());

            Auth::user()->offer()->save($offer);

            Alert::success('Offer is succesfully added!', 'Good job!')->persistent("Close");

        return Redirect::back();

    }
```

Comment: Read the message more carefully.  Your server is returning an error; that's just a stack trace.  Look at the network tab.

Comment: But WHY? At backend I have this in Laravel: public function store(Requests\OfferRequest $request)
    {

            $offer = new Offer($request->all());

            Auth::user()->offer()->save($offer);

            Alert::success('Offer is succesfully added!', 'Good job!')->persistent("Close");

        return Redirect::back();

    }

Comment: cross-domain can't cause a 500. 500 is a server-side error...

Comment: Sorry abou this, I update question

Comment: MonkeyBusiness, please check the logs from your webserver, or see what the error is from the network console (as @SLaks has mentioned).

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Ur7Zp2c.png

Comment: So what can be a problem here?